# R - How to transform a decimal column in a set of columns representing bin numbers

Tags: r, binary

I have a data frame of this type:
[image]

I want to transform the decimal numbers of the Positions column into 16 digits binary numbers:
[image]

So in the second tab, the Positions column should be replaced with 16 columns.

- "NULL" should be replaced with: 0000000000000000
- 5544 should be replaced with: 0001010110101000
- 4096 should be replaced with: 0000000000001000

At the moment I came up with this:

```
Impl_Pos[which(Impl_Pos == "NULL")] <- 0
Impl_Pos <- c(paste(Impl_Pos))
View(Impl_Pos)

Impl_Pos_Unl=unlist(Impl_Pos, use.names=FALSE)
Impl_Pos <- sapply(Impl_Pos_Unl,function(x){as.integer(intToBits(x))})
Impl_Pos <- t(Impl_Pos[1:16,])
```

Which results in a 16x4 matrix of integers (here shown only the first group of columns):
[image]

But it does not seem so trivial to give names to these columns, neither to merge them with the rest of my dataset.
I tried with these 2 bunches of code, but no results:

```
colnames(Impl_Pos) <- paste('pos', 1:16)
aggregate(pos 16 + pos 15 +...+ pos 2 + pos 1, Impl_Pos, sum)

library("plyr")
ddply(Impl_Pos, .(pos 16 + pos 15 +...+ pos 2 + pos 1), numcolwise(sum))
aggregate(Impl_Pos[,c(pos 16 + pos 15 +...+ pos 2 + pos 1)], by=list(Impl_Pos$Molar), "sum")
```

Answer (score 0):

## Binary in 16 columns

If you want to blow up the decimal to 16 columns, try below :

```
#Creating a dummy data frame similar to your example
df <- data.frame(ID = c("A","B","C"),Positions = c("NULL","5445","453"))

#Making sure that "Positions" column has characters instead of factors
df$Positions <- as.character(df$Positions)

#Impute the "NULL" values with a character "0"
df$Positions[which(df$Positions == "NULL")] <- "0"

#Change characters to integers.
df$Positions <- as.integer(df$Positions)

Impl_Pos <- sapply(df$Positions , function(x){as.integer(intToBits(x))})

#Do not transpose here. Only select the first 16 elements
Impl_Pos <- Impl_Pos[1:16,]

#Apply the "rev" (reverse) function columnwise to make 
#the order of the binary representation more intutive
Impl_Pos <- t(apply(Impl_Pos ,2,rev))

#Creating column names. I felt a numbering from 15 to 0
#might be more intuitive as they correspond to the powers of 2 at that position
pos <- rep("Pos",16)
c_names <- paste0(pos,15:0)
colnames(Impl_Pos) <- c_names

#Attach to the original df
df <- cbind(df,Impl_Pos)
```

Output I got was:

```
ID Positions Pos15 Pos14 Pos13 Pos12 Pos11 Pos10 Pos9 Pos8 Pos7 Pos6 Pos5 Pos4 Pos3 Pos2 Pos1 Pos0
A         0     0     0     0     0     0     0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
B      5445     0     0     0     1     0     1    0    1    0    1    0    0    0    1    0    1
C       453     0     0     0     0     0     0    0    1    1    1    0    0    0    1    0    1
```

## Alternate solution (suggestion)

As per your question, you are trying to split the binary into 16 columns. If it suits you to get the entire binary in one column (felt intuitive for me) - see the below code

```
#Creating a dummy data frame similar to your example
df <- data.frame(ID = c("A","B","C"),Positions = c("NULL","5445","453"))

#Making sure that "Positions" column has characters instead of factors
df$Positions <- as.character(df$Positions)

#Impute the "NULL" values with a character "0"
df$Positions[which(df$Positions == "NULL")] <- "0"

#Change characters to integers.
df$Positions <- as.integer(df$Positions)

#Vectorizing a function on the Positions column
##intToBits give a vector of binaries
##select the first 16 (as you needed only that precision)
##reverse that vector to get it in the desired format
##Use collapse = "" to merge the vector to a single string while pasting

bin_vec <-
  sapply(df$Positions, function(x) {
    temp <- intToBits(x)
    temp <- paste0(rev(temp[1:16]), collapse = "")
    return(temp)
  })

#Bind vector as column to original df
df <- cbind(df,Binary = bin_vec)
```

The output that I got was :

```
ID Positions           Binary
A         0 0000000000000000
B      5445 0001010101000101
C       453 0000000111000101
```